# Телеграм-бот на питоне не отправляет стикер! Примеры из интернета не работают

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
import telebot
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Привет мир!')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.from_user.id == 'мой ID':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'Здравствуй, хозяин!')
    else:
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAIFtGLw6JmEUNd9nv4EpmLdfO2Sc13JAALrAAPww8AOBEFNY5iRmfUpBA')
        # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'У тебя нет надо мной власти!')


while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0, timeout=60)
    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
```

в блоке else работает только закомментированная строка, метод send_sticker не работает!никаких ошибок бот не выдает, просто молчит, в чат ничего не приходит.
P.S. огромное спасибо за поддержку!!!`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а стикер такой хоть есть?

Comment: попробуйте вставить этот id стикера `CAACAgIAAxkBAAEFgWNi8QiHct92SeyJsKP4BIE3CgOlygACJAMAArVx2gafiis85FHPvSkE`

Comment: Извиняюсь, токен стикера поправил, тот, что сейчас да, есть, я получил его от бота, просто скопировал не полностью, до этого был целиком, но не суть.
Попробовал Ваш токен стикера, но без изменений, реакция 0

Comment: А у Вас работает?

Answer (score 0):

Спустя 24 дня вопрос решился, код рабочий, дело оказалось в самой библиотеке pytelegrambotapi, она оказалась битой! Подсказал пользователь с телеграм-чата, который я нашел, спасибо ему большое. Проблема была решена двумя командами:
pip uninstall pytelegrambotapi
и
pip install pytelegrambotapi
после чего метод send_sticker заработал!
Век живи, век учись...